# hivemq illegal state exception

Tags: java, hivemq

I'm trying to develop a hivemq authentication plugin.
I have followed the hivemq guide for creating a project, and I am not doing anything in the plugin itself. I return true immediately.

```
mosquitto_sub -t hey
```

When I try to connect with mosquitto_sub using the command above, I get the error below.

```
INFO  - Started HiveMQ 1.4.2 in 1528ms
ERROR - An unexpecteed error occured:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: illegal state during login of client mosq_sub_12248_ahmetce
at com.dcsquare.hivemq.handler.protocol.ConnectMessageHandler.logStatus(ConnectMessageHandler.java:176)
at com.dcsquare.hivemq.handler.protocol.ConnectMessageHandler.processSuccessfulLogin(ConnectMessageHandler.java:114)
```

This is the code I'm testing with: http://pastie.org/8555786#22-23

Has anyone had a similar error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regression in the 1.4.x HiveMQ line and is fixed in all HiveMQ versions > 1.4.3. The solution is to upgrade the HiveMQ version to a more recent one. (At the time of this writing, 1.4.3 is the most recent stable version, but hotfix versions are available.)

Comment: I can confirm the problem was fixed ( tried "return true" and "return false" scenarios) by testing the plugin in development release of broker.